# Read state string for weblogic.jms.extensions.WLMessage Message

Tags: jms, weblogic

I am trying to read the state string for messages on a queue[image]

I am using the following code to read the state string, but state string always returns ""

```
JmsMessageDetailsBag detailsBag = new JmsMessageDetailsBag();
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = OpenTwinsFrontendUtilities.getInitialContext( false );
            // lookup the queue object
            Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup( queueName );

            // lookup the queue connection factory
            QueueConnectionFactory connFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup( "jms/EJBJMSQueueConnectionFactory" );

            // create a queue connection
            QueueConnection queueConn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();

            // create a queue session
            QueueSession queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession( false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );

            // create a queue browser
            QueueBrowser queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser( queue );

            // start the connection
            queueConn.start();

            // browse the messages
            Enumeration<?> e = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
            // count number of messages
            while ( e.hasMoreElements() ) {
                javax.jms.Message message = (javax.jms.Message) e.nextElement();
                JmsMessageDetails details = new JmsMessageDetails();
                weblogic.jms.extensions.JMSMessageInfo info = new weblogic.jms.extensions.JMSMessageInfo( ((weblogic.jms.extensions.WLMessage) message) );
                details.setMessageState( info.getStateString( info.getState() != 0 ? info.getState() : 1 ) );
                details.setMessageId( message.getJMSMessageID() );
                details.setTimeStamp( new OpenTwinsDateAndTimeImpl( new Date( message.getJMSTimestamp() ) ) );
                details.setMessageBody( new OpenTwinsCLOBImpl( JsonJMSMessage.serializerPretty.toJson( message ) ) );
                detailsBag.add( details );

            }
```

But info.getState() always returns 0;
Is there some other way to get the correct state

Comment: So when you print out `getStateString` does it say `visible` and just the `getState` portion is failing? API for reference to anyone looking: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50629_01/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/messaging/runtime/MessageInfo.html#getStateString()

Comment: When I print getStateString() it returns "" (an empty string) and getState returns 0